# Loop through cell dependents

Tags: vba

this expresses what I would like to do but obviously does not work. I think what I am trying to do is clear:

Get a cell, get its dependencies count, and output all of them.

Thanks in advance for any input

```
            Sub Extract()
            Dim i As Integer

                    For i = 1 To Workbooks("myBook.xls").Worksheets(1).Cells(14, 5).Dependents.Count
                        Debug.Print (Workbooks("myBook.xls").Worksheets(1).Cells(14, 5).Dependents(i))
                    Next i
            End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
Sub Extract()
Dim i As Range
    With Workbooks("Book1.xls").Worksheets(1).Cells(14, 5)
        For Each i In .Dependents
            Debug.Print i.Value i.Address
    Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

HTH!

**Edit**

`.Dependents` is the [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) os `.DirectDependents`, and I'm not sure which of them you want ... try both!